# Does eclipse.org have a user feedback forum?

Tags: eclipse

I'm not talking about bug reporting. How do they decide what features to put in new releases? Presumably there is some stream of user commentary somewhere that informs their decision making process.  The IDE seems so flexible it's hard to imagine that it isn't being driven by some communal wish list.  Ideally they would have something like stackoverflow =)

Anyway, I've been looking over their site for years now, and have yet to find anything like this. Could be I'm just blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, regardless of what is discussed in the news groups, the [bug system](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) is the mechanism to use if you have features that you want added.  Just mark the severity as 'enhancement'.

Comment: ah, i didn't presume to call some of my wish list items 'bugs' w/the existing ide, so didn't even think of the bug reports.  So like if I'd like mark-occurrances to not *automatically* highlight, but maybe only change in response to a key combination, it's an enhancement..

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Eclipse.org news portal](http://www.eclipse.org/newsportal/).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, code speaks. If you want an Eclipse project to provide some functionality you care about, you really need to get involved with the project itself. Bug reports are a great way to propose new functionality, but if you're serious about it, consider contributing some of your own effort into the process.